# Why don’t the images show horizontally when there’s a `<div>` in between?

Tags: html, css

I try to use the tags `<ul>` and `<li>` to list images and `<div>`s horizontally, but it didn’t work:

```css
.stitching {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style-type: none;margin: 0px">
  <li class="stitching">
    <img src="images/S.png" style="height: 200px;">
    <div class="blackblock"></div>
    <img src="images/r.JPG" style="height: 200px">
  </li>
</ul>
```

But after I delete tag `<div>`, it works! I don’t know why, can anyone help?

Comment: Because you didn’t set the `<div>` to `display: inline;` or `inline-block`.

Comment: `<div>` are block elements.  Try a `<span>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div>` elements are `display: block` so they took the all the width and your second `img` is wrapping. To avoid this, you have many solution:

1- use a `<span>` element because they are `inline` element so they can have elements aside them.

2- in css, to your `.blackblock` element, give the properties `display: inline` or `inline-block` so it will get the same behaviour than a `span`

3- to your `.stitching` element, change the `display: inline-block` to `flex`. In default it will horizontally but you can after that use the property `flex-direction: column` to make it vertically.